# Magento display custom attribute using addAttribtueToFilter

Tags: magento, attributes, frontend

I created a very simple attribute called "unit" inside attribute set "unitSet" with to dropdown value "/EA" & "/LB"
I have enable

scope -> global 
 
Used in Product Listing -> yes 
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end -> yes 
Used for Sorting in Product Listing -> yes

```
<?php 
            $newProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('*')
                            ->getProductCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('Unit', "/LB") // option 1
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('Unit', 1) // option 2
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
?>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <?php foreach($newProducts as $newProduct): ?>
            <?php echo $newProduct->getName(); ?>
            <?endforeach?>
        </div>
?>
```

the filter don't seem to work at all? can some one help?

Comment: what do you mean it's not working? are you not getting any products? is the filter for the custom attribute not woking? is the attribute not available on the product's model?

Comment: the filter didn't seem to work, when I remove the filter I can out put all status 1 products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does not actually filter dropdown attribuets by their actual value (in this case '/LB'), instead you have to obtain the id of the value, and then filter by that value, there many many ways to do this, I found a simple one

```
<?php 
        $newProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('*')
                        ->getProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addFieldToFilter(
                            'unit',
                               array('eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                                    ->getAttribute('unit')
                                    ->getSource()
                                    ->getOptionId("/LB")
                               )
                         );
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
?>
```

Alternatively,

```
function getAttributeOptionValue($arg_attribute, $arg_value) {
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach($options as $option) {
        if ($option['label'] == $arg_value) {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }

    return false;
}

<?php 
        $newProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('*')
                        ->getProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addFieldToFilter(
                            'unit',
                               array('eq' => getAttributeOptionValue('unit','/LB')
                               )
                         );
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
?>
```